# How to Punctuate a "Play on Words"

Tags: punctuation

My article is titled, Bridge Snacks for Thought. Obviously, a play on words for "Food for Thought." Seems I should punctuate it: "Bridge Snacks" for Thought.

And, it also could be Bridge "Snacks" for Thought. Or, something else...

I should add that local bridge clubs, snacks always are served.

Comment: Why use the quotes at all? That seems to me like a big red arrow labeled "Hey, just in case you're too dense to get it, this is a joke".

Comment: You're asking something completely subjective. Without more criteria, any answer could be as good as any other . . .

Comment: *Food for Thinkin'* might be more effective if the article is about "brain foods" that may enhance play performance ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need no quotation marks.

The lingering doubt you have is due to the rampant abuse of them seen everywhere in modern life.  But you are neither quoting someone, nor defining a term of art.  No quotes.

Comment: I almost feel like we need a symbol for "air quotes" as a form of  quotation marks in "quotes"